# UITextView ignoring AttributedText in Retina

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I've been working on a bug now on and off (because it's driving me crazy) for a couple of weeks now, and I just can't seem to get to the bottom of it so I'm reaching out in hopes someone can shed some light on this for me...

I've got a basic `UITextView` setup in a XIB file and have set the font using an included font, but not the default (in this case "Avenir") and then I'm using a couple of lines of code to change the line height by using the Attributed Text property. I should also mention I'm using ARC.

The output looks perfect on an iPad mini (or the normal iPad on the simulator) but on an iPad retina (or retina simulator) the output get's knocked back to the system default font - Helvetica, although it maintains the line spacing.

I've tried creating the `UITextView` programatically rather than in the XIB and still no luck. Here is the code I'm using to set the Attributed Text:

```
NSString *string = theTextView.text;

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 48.f;

NSMutableAttributedString *aStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
[aStr addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0,[string length])];

theTextView.attributedText = aStr;
```

From what I can tell, on a retina device, for some reason the `UITextView` seems to be holding a double set of attributed strings. When I print

```
NSLog(@"Font Attributes: %@", theTextView.attributedText);
```

This is the output I get:

**Non Retina**

```
Font Attributes: Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x714c930> font-family: \"Avenir-Roman\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 24px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 48/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
```

**Retina**

```
Font Attributes: Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x71ed950> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 48/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x71e67d0> font-family: \"Avenir-Roman\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 24px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 48/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
```

I've created a simple example project of the problem on GitHub as well -

https://github.com/mpatteson/UITextViewBug

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody else who might stumble across this, after not getting what I needed here I used one of my dedicated Apple Support tickets to open a discussion with one of their engineers regarding the issue.

He confirmed that this is indeed a bug within iOS that cannot be remedied - you can either set the font, in which case line heights and spacing will be ignored, or the other way around in which case the font will reset to system defaults. He did say that a quick test seems to show that it has been fixed in iOS 7 Beta 2 thankfully but still not great.

For my purposes I have replaced the `UITextView` with a `UIWebView` so that I can control the content with CSS

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. For non-retina devices and simulators it worked but when I switched to a retina device or simulator the font was standard helvetica with the same outputs as you had.
For me it worked when I specified the font directly in the code (in the Interface Builder it was correctly set). So add a line like this:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Roman" size:24.0];
[aStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0,[string length])];
```

Comment: I've tried adding this and the font does indeed fix itself, but my specified line height is now being ignored, making it all a bit pointless. Do they conflict somehow?

Comment: I also just tried putting both attributes into a dictionary and adding them together using the addAttributes:range: method, but same result. If both are specified then the line height is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adjusting your minimum line height for the scale?

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 48.0 * [UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

Comment: That does indeed change the line height to 96 on Retina, but doesn't do much else. Just spaces the Helvetica text more of course, but the duplicated attributes are still present.